# How to understand a CosmosDb exception (InternalServerErrorException)?

Tags: java, exception, azure-cosmosdb

I receive sporadic an errors from the Cosmos Db driver like the following with a large message which is not helpful for me.

- How can I read this exception?
- How can I find the failing command or code line?
- What is the cause of the exception?
- How can I fix this?

```
{"ClassName":"InternalServerErrorException","userAgent":"azsdk-java-cosmos/4.17.0 WindowsServer2019/10.0 JRE/11.0.15",
"statusCode":500,"resourceAddress":"rntbd://172.22.173.30:10251/apps/DocDbApp/services/DocDbMaster0/partitions/780e44f4-38c8-11e6-8106-8cdcd42c33be/replicas/1p/",
"error":"{\"Errors\":[\"An unknown error occurred while processing this request. If the issue persists, please contact Azure Support: http://aka.ms/azure-support\"]}",
"innerErrorMessage":"[\"An unknown error occurred while processing this request. If the issue persists, please contact Azure Support: http://aka.ms/azure-support\"]",
"causeInfo":null,
"responseHeaders":"{x-ms-current-replica-set-size=1, x-ms-last-state-change-utc=Wed, 27 Apr 2022 20:54:25.931 GMT, x-ms-request-duration-ms=12.363, x-ms-session-token=0:-1#6689, lsn=6689, x-ms-request-charge=2.67, x-ms-schemaversion=1.12, x-ms-transport-request-id=63217, x-ms-number-of-read-regions=0, x-ms-current-write-quorum=1, x-ms-cosmos-quorum-acked-llsn=6689, x-ms-quorum-acked-lsn=6689, x-ms-activity-id=73c9465a-c670-11ec-b802-a31d99fd4ad1, x-ms-xp-role=0, x-ms-global-Committed-lsn=-1, x-ms-cosmos-llsn=6689, x-ms-serviceversion= version=2.14.0.0}",
"cosmosDiagnostics":{"userAgent":"azsdk-java-cosmos/4.17.0 WindowsServer2019/10.0 JRE/11.0.15","requestLatencyInMs":79,"requestStartTimeUTC":"2022-04-27T21:24:42.285251300Z","requestEndTimeUTC":"2022-04-27T21:24:42.365236700Z","responseStatisticsList":[{"storeResult":{"storePhysicalAddress":"rntbd://172.22.173.30:10251/apps/DocDbApp/services/DocDbMaster0/partitions/780e44f4-38c8-11e6-8106-8cdcd42c33be/replicas/1p/","lsn":6689,"globalCommittedLsn":-1,"partitionKeyRangeId":"","isValid":true,"statusCode":500,"subStatusCode":0,"isGone":false,"isNotFound":false,"isInvalidPartition":false,"isThroughputControlRequestRateTooLarge":false,"requestCharge":1.0,"itemLSN":-1,"sessionToken":"-1#6689","backendLatencyInMs":12.363,
"exception":"[\"An unknown error occurred while processing this request. If the issue persists, please contact Azure Support: http://aka.ms/azure-support\"]",
"transportRequestTimeline":[{"eventName":"created","startTimeUTC":"2022-04-27T21:24:42.285251300Z","durationInMicroSec":0},{"eventName":"queued","startTimeUTC":"2022-04-27T21:24:42.285251300Z","durationInMicroSec":0},
{"eventName":"channelAcquisitionStarted","startTimeUTC":"2022-04-27T21:24:42.285251300Z","durationInMicroSec":0},
{"eventName":"pipelined","startTimeUTC":"2022-04-27T21:24:42.285251300Z","durationInMicroSec":990},
{"eventName":"transitTime","startTimeUTC":"2022-04-27T21:24:42.286242Z","durationInMicroSec":13014},
{"eventName":"received","startTimeUTC":"2022-04-27T21:24:42.299256400Z","durationInMicroSec":0},
{"eventName":"completed","startTimeUTC":"2022-04-27T21:24:42.299256400Z","durationInMicroSec":981}],
"rntbdRequestLengthInBytes":297,"rntbdResponseLengthInBytes":353,"requestPayloadLengthInBytes":0,"responsePayloadLengthInBytes":null,"channelTaskQueueSize":1,"pendingRequestsCount":1,"serviceEndpointStatistics":{"availableChannels":3,"acquiredChannels":0,"executorTaskQueueSize":0,"inflightRequests":1,"lastSuccessfulRequestTime":"2022-04-27T21:24:31.868Z","lastRequestTime":"2022-04-27T21:24:31.859Z","createdTime":"2022-04-27T21:16:17.690994800Z","isClosed":false}},"requestResponseTimeUTC":"2022-04-27T21:24:42.300237900Z","requestResourceType":"DocumentCollection","requestOperationType":"ReadFeed"},
{"storeResult":{"storePhysicalAddress":"rntbd://172.22.173.30:10251/apps/DocDbApp/services/DocDbMaster0/partitions/780e44f4-38c8-11e6-8106-8cdcd42c33be/replicas/1p/",
"lsn":6689,"globalCommittedLsn":-1,
"partitionKeyRangeId":null,"isValid":true,"statusCode":200,"subStatusCode":0,"isGone":false,"isNotFound":false,"isInvalidPartition":false,
"isThroughputControlRequestRateTooLarge":false,
"requestCharge":1.67,"itemLSN":-1,"sessionToken":"-1#6689","backendLatencyInMs":10.778,"exception":null,
"transportRequestTimeline":[{"eventName":"created","startTimeUTC":"2022-04-27T21:24:42.285251300Z","durationInMicroSec":0},
{"eventName":"queued","startTimeUTC":"2022-04-27T21:24:42.285251300Z","durationInMicroSec":0},
{"eventName":"channelAcquisitionStarted","startTimeUTC":"2022-04-27T21:24:42.285251300Z","durationInMicroSec":990},
{"eventName":"pipelined","startTimeUTC":"2022-04-27T21:24:42.286242Z","durationInMicroSec":0},
{"eventName":"transitTime","startTimeUTC":"2022-04-27T21:24:42.286242Z","durationInMicroSec":78994},
{"eventName":"received","startTimeUTC":"2022-04-27T21:24:42.365236700Z","durationInMicroSec":0},
{"eventName":"completed","startTimeUTC":"2022-04-27T21:24:42.365236700Z","durationInMicroSec":0}],
"rntbdRequestLengthInBytes":297,"rntbdResponseLengthInBytes":21521,"requestPayloadLengthInBytes":0,"responsePayloadLengthInBytes":21240,"channelTaskQueueSize":1,"pendingRequestsCount":0,"serviceEndpointStatistics":{"availableChannels":2,"acquiredChannels":1,"executorTaskQueueSize":0,"inflightRequests":2,"lastSuccessfulRequestTime":"2022-04-27T21:24:31.868Z","lastRequestTime":"2022-04-27T21:24:42.285Z","createdTime":"2022-04-27T21:16:17.690994800Z","isClosed":false}},"requestResponseTimeUTC":"2022-04-27T21:24:42.365236700Z","requestResourceType":"DocumentCollection","requestOperationType":"ReadFeed"}],"supplementalResponseStatisticsList":[],"addressResolutionStatistics":{},"regionsContacted":[],"retryContext":{"statusAndSubStatusCodes":null,"retryCount":0,"retryLatency":0},"metadataDiagnosticsContext":{"metadataDiagnosticList":null},"serializationDiagnosticsContext":{"serializationDiagnosticsList":null},"gatewayStatistics":null,"systemInformation":{"usedMemory":"116830 KB","availableMemory":"407458 KB","systemCpuLoad":"(2022-04-27T21:24:16.127472200Z 96,7%), (2022-04-27T21:24:21.160494800Z 99,9%), (2022-04-27T21:24:26.126473Z 98,8%), (2022-04-27T21:24:31.142447Z 99,7%), (2022-04-27T21:24:36.147247800Z 100,0%), (2022-04-27T21:24:41.132241600Z 100,0%)","availableProcessors":8},"clientCfgs":{"id":-5,"connectionMode":"DIRECT","numberOfClients":6,"connCfg":{"rntbd":"(cto:PT5S, rto:PT5S, icto:PT0S, ieto:PT1H, mcpe:130, mrpc:30, cer:false)","gw":"(cps:1000, rto:PT5S, icto:null, p:false)","other":"(ed: true, cs: false)"},"consistencyCfg":"(consistency: null, mm: true, prgns: [])"}}}
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.directconnectivity.rntbd.RntbdRequestManager.messageReceived(RntbdRequestManager.java:807)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.directconnectivity.rntbd.RntbdRequestManager.channelRead(RntbdRequestManager.java:181)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1368)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1234)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1280)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Answer (score 0):

5XX errors are always service errors that usually can only be resolved by a support engineer. Nearly always the information you are looking for is found right up at the top of the error as it is here.

"An unknown error occurred while processing this request. If the issue persists, please contact Azure Support: [http://aka.ms/azure-support\"](http://aka.ms/azure-support%5C%22)

Comment: My previous contacts with the support was not helpful.